# Getting javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes exception

Tags: java, encryption, rsa, private-key

Scenario : I am working on a scenario where AES algorithm is used for actual data encryption & decryption. And using RSA algorithm, AES key is getting encrypted/decrypted.

Issue : When I am trying to retrieve the AES private key using RSA decrypt() method, it is throwing an - `javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: Data must not be longer than 256 bytes` exception.
Also, observed one thing this is not getting thrown everytime, sometimes it works correctly, sometimes it doesnot.

Here is a code:

```
public byte[] decryptKey(final String keyToDecrypt, final String key) throws Exception 
{
        PKCS8EncodedKeySpec spec = new PKCS8EncodedKeySpec(Base64.getDecoder().decode(key));
        PrivateKey pKey = keyFactory.generatePrivate(spec);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,pKey);

        return cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(keyToDecrypt));
}
```

Any idea how to fix this intermittent issue? Your help is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Saurabh

Comment: None of the existing questions and answers located with a [search for the error message](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=data+must+not+be+longer+than+256+bytes) helped?

Comment: Saurabh, unfortunately there are multiple possibilities for what you're seeing. To really diagnose this we'd need to see how the data is transformed at each step as it starts out as a 1. key ==> 2). RSA encrypted ==> 3. (base64?) encoded ==> 4. transmitted to the recipient ==> received at the recipient ==> 5. appears as the arguments to `decryptKey`. With that information we might be able to spot any bugs as well as test these transformations using our own RSA keys.